# virual Hosts for laravel and angular on Nginx

Tags: angular, laravel, nginx

I have to projects

- Laravel API `Running on 127.0.0.1:8000`
- Angular SPA `Running on 127.0.0.1:4200` 
  trying to make them work on
- `chp.test` for laravel
- `client.chp.test` for Angular
  I managed to get the laravel API to work using `Valet for linux` but not able to get the angular server work I tried the following steps on [this medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-properly-get-angular-and-nginx-working-together-for-development-3e5d158734bf)
  by adding a `config/nginx.conf` file the link it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enable` with the following configuration within it

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name client.chp.test;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        proxy_set_header Host       $host;
    }
}
```

and I run my dev server using this command

```
$ ng serve -o --poll=1000 --public-host http://client.chp.test
```

but still unable to access it from the browser

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux, but on mac, you need to append `127.0.0.1  client.chp.test` to `/etc/hosts` file in order to `test` domain start to work. can you give it a try on Linux?

Comment: this was my first shot but, didn't work